# a problem about continuous functions on closed intervals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

This is the problem:

> Let  *f* be a continuous function on a finite interval [*a*,*b*]. Suppose that *f* (*x*) > $0$ for all x in [*a*,*b*]. **Prove** that there is an $\alpha$ > $0$ such that *f* (*x*) > $\alpha$ for all *x* in [*a*,*b*].

If ***f* be a continuous function on a finite interval [*a*,*b*].** Then *f* is uniformly continuous on [*a*,*b*] and I can prove that. But the thing bothers me at this point how can I **show/prove** that there is an $\alpha$ > $0$ such that *f* (*x*) > $\alpha$ for all *x* in [*a*,*b*] ?

Comment: Let $\alpha=\inf f$. As $[a,b]$ is compact, there exists $x\in[a,b]$ with $f(x)=\alpha$. --- Or note that $\frac1{f(x)}$ is continuous and bounded

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets. Thus the image of $[a,b]$ will be some closed interval $[\alpha, \beta]$. As $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$, it must be that $\alpha > 0$.

Stated differently: continuous functions on compact sets attain their infimum and supremum values. Since $f(x) > 0$, the infinimum must be bigger than $0$. Denote it by $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful.